# JSON JavaScript with multiple occurrences.

Tags: javascript, json, youtube-data-api

Im using the Youtube Data API. Im doing a simple API call to get the latest 5 videos from a user, using the playlist method. The JSON file has videoID listed 5 times. I know that I could concatenate the results. I was asking if I could  store each one as separate variable?
All help with be amazing. Thanks James, Happy Easter :)

Comment: Can you post example json?

Comment: I would Copy past it. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource-representation. When you there more than one it will repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arrayOfVideos = JSON.parse(...)
var arrayOfVideoIDs = arrayOfVideos.map(function (video) {
    return video.videoID
})
```

Comment: Thanks you. :) Have a internet cookie

Comment: @JamesCoombesXD if this helped, can you accept my answer?